# Customize my site

Tags: user-profile, user-profile-service, my-site, mysite, mysites

We are going to heavily customize My Sites, but will use standard components (web parts used in my site) and add some libraries and lists to every Profile.

In this regard I am wondering how to go about with the tasks. Is it Ok to edit `person.aspx` or do I create a new Page Layout and set it as Welcome Page and customize there?

Comment: there is JS based provisioning that you could consider: http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2014/09/javascript-JSOM-based-provisioning-in-sharepoint-office-365.html

Answer (score 1):

Its advisable to create a custom Page Layout based on your requirement. Then create a Welcome Page out of that.

Once completed, you can create a PowerShell Script which goes and create this Page for existing My Sites. And also change the Welcome Page to the newly created page.

Comment: Thanks for your comments Amal. Is it not possible to have features activate automatically on provisioning of my site ? 

It would be a bad solution to manually activate features each time a new person is hired (and gets a my-site in the portal of the company).

Comment: Yes you can have a feature. Use Feature Stapling to activate it automatically.

Comment: Nice. I came across another issue. When using a custom page layout as a welcome, the query string will no longer have the username. Any ideas how to go around this ?